# if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ has a convergence radius $R<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

I'm supposed to prove  the Title.
I have tried to prove by contradiction and using the limit definition but with not much luck.
thanks for the help

Comment: Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$. What can you conclude about the radius of convergence?

Comment: Hint: Choose $x$  with $R<x<1$, and note that $\sum a_n x^n$ diverges although $\sum|x^n|<\infty$.

Comment: thanks! should have solved it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If $R<1$ , then $ \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}>1.$ Hence $|a_n|^{1/n}>1$ for infinitely many $n$, thus $|a_n|>1$ for infinitely many $n$. This gives the result.